# Integration Of Openerp with Moodle

Tags: odoo, moodle

I am trying to make an integration between moodle and openerp. In openerp when I create an event and do confirm to that event the following exception is thrown:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\xmlrpclib.py", line 1264, in request
return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
File "C:\Python27\lib\xmlrpclib.py", line 1312, in single_request
response.msg,ProtocolError: <ProtocolError for    127.0.0.1/moodle/webservice/xmlrpc/server.php?wstoken=8fc9790386584d3eab4b4112191051af: 404 Not Found>
```

I am working openerp7 and windows7

Comment: What's you moodle version? Does the path exists in the moodle installation? if you go to that page with a browser, what do you see? 404 error or a blank page?

Answer (score 0):

try following code that is of openerp 8.
Create one method in that write following.

```
moodle_config_wiz=self.env['event.moodle.config.wiz'].search([])
url=moodle_config_wiz[0].url
sock = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(url)   
sock.core_course_get_courses()
```